# How to get array size which is inside an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array which contains objects like this:

```
dataSet = [{question:"",options:[{subject:"",teacher:""}]}]
```

How can I get the length of the options array?

Comment: `dataset[0].options.length`

Comment: Well, right now, that's invalid JS. Anyway, I suppose the answer is more than `data-Set[0].options.length`... Is that all the information we truly need to answer your question or there's more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataSet` itself an array. So get the first index of it and then length of `options` in it like following.

```js
var dataSet = [{question:"", options:[{subject:"",teacher:""}]}]
alert(dataSet[0].options.length);
```